# Upload image from Parse Hosting

Tags: express, parse-platform, cloud, hosting, ejs

I'm trying to upload an image from a form in Parse's hosting solution. I've tried to find a good tutorial or something to start from, but I don't understand where I should begin. The feature is really basic so I've probably stumbled across solutions, but all of them seems so complicated and unnecessary. In short I want to have these snippets:

```
<form action="/uploadimage" method="post" id="uploadimageform">
    <input type="file" id="image">
    <button>Upload</button>
</form>


app.post('/uploadimage', function(req, res) {
    // var object has a File field called image
    object.set('image', [the image]);
    // save object
});
```

Do I have to use Backbone which the [AnyImg](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Anyimg) example uses? Is there a simpler way to solve this?